# How to install bitcoind on Ubuntu 20?

Tags: ubuntu, vps, bitcoin, bitcoind

I am having the trouble with installation of bitcoind on Ubuntu v20 VPS system.
How i try to make it done with official tutorial:

"If you use Ubuntu, you don’t need to compile bitcoind and bitcoin-cli from source. You can simply add the official Bitcoin PPA."

This is my commands:

```bash
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bitcoind
```

When i try to add repository I am getting this funny error message and when i proceed with enter the system seems to be done with it but actually it does not add repository!!

When i type this command I got this message :
Command : sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
Error:

> root@vultr:~# sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin  NOT
> MAINTAINED. The OS-library linking packages here had a series of
> issues.
>
> PLEASE DOWNLOAD DIRECTLY FROM bitcoincore.org (and verify the
> signatures of said files).
>
> IF YOU WANT AUTO-UPDATES, please see the officially-maintained snap
> package - https://github.com/bitcoin-core/packaging/tree/master/snap
> More info: [https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/ubuntu/bitcoin](https://launchpad.net/%7Ebitcoin/+archive/ubuntu/bitcoin)
> Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Then when i press Enter to continue i am getting this message:

```
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [107 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98.3 kB]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

And after that when i think everything is good and when i run the command
sudo apt-get update

and when update is done i try to push command :
sudo apt-get install bitcoind

and i get this error message:

```
root@vultr:~# sudo apt-get install bitcoind
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package bitcoind
root@vultr:~#
```

Please point me to solution or tell me where I am making mistake this is the biggest problem I ever saw till now.
I am not good with ubuntu and vps and this seem impossible to me,
Thank you so much!

Comment: You can see [here](http://www.estrellateyarde.org/encriptacion-y-criptografia/monedero-bitcoin-core-en-ubuntu) another way to install bitcoin-core

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had to go to the bitcoin.org website and find the link of the last tar.gz bitcoin.

For my example i did it like this:
type in the ubuntu

```bash
wget https://bitcoin.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.20.0/bitcoin-0.20.0-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz
```

then i unpack my tar.gz

> tar -xvf bitcoin-0.20.0-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz

then i go to the bitcoin folder and move the files to
/usr/local/bin

and then i simply start bitcoind with

> bitcoind -daemon

to run it in the background :)

hope this helps :)